# Flask API returns Null for simple input

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm new to this, but I have started to learn how to make Flask API for ML.
I have wrote a code that should just return inputed text, but it returns Null. This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

APP = Flask(__name__)
API = Api(APP)

class Predict(Resource):

    @staticmethod
    def post():

        json_data = reqparse.RequestParser()
        json_data.add_argument('Title')
        json_data.add_argument('Text')

        json_data = json_data.parse_args()  # creates dict
        print("INPUT DATA", json_data)

        return json_data, 200


API.add_resource(Predict, '/predict')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP.run(debug=True, port='1180')
```

My API link is: http://127.0.0.1:1180/predict

I have tried to test in in Postman, I set POST request, added API link, and in Body field I added this:

```
{
        "Title": "test1",
        "Text": "test2"
}
```

My result is this:

```
{
    "Title": null,
    "Text": null
}
```

Why Im getting this result?

Comment: you add arguments without value. Did you check what you have in `json_data` before you add arguments?

Comment: I tested your code using python module `requests` and it works correctly

Comment: I get `null` only if I send your data as raw text, but if I send it as real JSON or FORM then it works. SO you simply use `POSTMAN` in wrong way - you send data in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it with python module `requests`

---

Code works for me if I send it as FORM data - `data=data`

```
import requests

data = {
        "Title": "test1",
        "Text": "test2"
}

r = requests.post('http://localhost:1180/predict', data=data)

print(r.text)
print(r.json())
```

It also works if I send it as JSON data - `json=data`

```
import requests

data = {
        "Title": "test1",
        "Text": "test2"
}

r = requests.post('http://localhost:1180/predict', json=data)

print(r.text)
print(r.json())
```

It gives `null` only if I send it as raw text instead of FORM data - `data='''{ text }'''`

```
import requests

data = '''{
        "Title": "test1",
        "Text": "test2"
}'''

r = requests.post('http://localhost:1180/predict', data=data)

print(r.text)
print(r.json())
```

And if send it as raw text instead of JSON data - `json='''{ text }'''` -
then I get `{"message": "Internal Server Error"}`

```
import requests

data = '''{
        "Title": "test1",
        "Text": "test2"
}'''

r = requests.post('http://localhost:1180/predict', json=data)

print(r.text)
print(r.json())
```

---

It may means you put data in `Postman` in wrong format.